# Parallel task (TPL) using for each statement in windows service

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

I am using for each statement in parallel task(TPL) in windows service, it is generating tasks continuously. Not able to fetch the number of tasks running currently.

Please find the sample code below:

```
Do
    Dim result As ParallelLoopResult = 
         Parallel.ForEach(taskcount, Function(item) createtask())
Loop
```

Here the Do Loop code section executes continuously in a windows service.

Comment: Why are you using Parallel ForEach to generate tasks? And what is taskcount? Can we see createtask() and taskcount, please?

Comment: What you mean by _Not able to fetch the number of tasks running currently_? What is `taskcount` - based on the name it can be integer, but `ForEach` method doesn't have first argument of `integer` type.

Comment: Task count is number of tasks to be created.                                            Do
    Dim result As ParallelLoopResult = 
         Parallel.ForEach(taskcount, Function(item) createtask())
 Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Parallel.ForEach(Of Integer)(taskcount, Function(item) requestandresponse(dsrecords.Tables(0).Rows(item)))).Wait()
    Task.WaitAll()
Loop

Comment: You can change the `createTask` method to handle the current number of **your** task running